# How do I populate JSON array to ASP:repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, repeater, asprepeater

I am stuck with porting and formatting JSON array into ASP:Repeater

**JSON Array:**

```
{
   "root":[
      {
         "prog_id":"P1000004",
         "prog_name":"Course1",
         "prog_banner":"",
         "isClientActive":"",
         "courses":[
            {
               "course_id":"C1000012",
               "course_name":"Course1-1",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            },
            {
               "course_id":"C1000013",
               "course_name":"Course1-2",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            }
         ]
      },
      {
         "prog_id":"P1000010",
         "prog_name":"Course2",
         "prog_banner":"1000010.jpg",
         "isClientActive":"active",
         "courses":[
            {
               "course_id":"C1000007",
               "course_name":"Course2-1",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            },
            {
               "course_id":"C1000008",
               "course_name":"Course2-2",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            },
            {
               "course_id":"C1000009",
               "course_name":"Course2-3",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            },
            {
               "course_id":"C1000010",
               "course_name":"Course2-4",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            },
            {
               "course_id":"C1000011",
               "course_name":"Course2-5",
               "course_description":"",
               "course_thumbnail":""
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
```

**Current Output:**

```
P1000004: Course1
Canorous_Academy.test.Cours[]

P1000010: Course2
Canorous_Academy.test.Cours[]
```

**Desired Output (Should look like):**

```
Repeater-Item 1
P1000004: Course1
Courses:
Course1-1
Course1-2

Repeater-Item 2
P1000010: Course2
Courses:
Course2-1
Course2-2
Course2-3
Course2-4
Course2-5
```

```js
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
string json="{\"root\":[{\"prog_id\":\"P1000004\",\"prog_name\":\"Course1\",\"prog_banner\":\"\",\"isClientActive\":\"\",\"courses\":[{\"course_id\":\"C1000012\",\"course_name\":\"Course1-1\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"},{\"course_id\":\"C1000013\",\"course_name\":\"Course1-2\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"}]},{\"prog_id\":\"P1000010\",\"prog_name\":\"Course2\",\"prog_banner\":\"1000010.jpg\",\"isClientActive\":\"active\",\"courses\":[{\"course_id\":\"C1000007\",\"course_name\":\"Course2-1\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"},{\"course_id\":\"C1000008\",\"course_name\":\"Course2-2\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"},{\"course_id\":\"C1000009\",\"course_name\":\"Course2-3\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"},{\"course_id\":\"C1000010\",\"course_name\":\"Course2-4\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"},{\"course_id\":\"C1000011\",\"course_name\":\"Course2-5\",\"course_description\":\"\",\"course_thumbnail\":\"\"}]}]}";
Rootobject _objRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
GetDataTableFromObjects(_objRoot.root);
Repeater1.DataSource = GetDataTableFromObjects(_objRoot.root);
Repeater1.DataBind();
}
public static DataTable GetDataTableFromObjects(object[] objects)
{
if (objects != null && objects.Length > 0)
{
Type t = objects[0].GetType();
DataTable dt = new DataTable(t.Name);
foreach (PropertyInfo pi in t.GetProperties())
{
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name));
}
foreach (var o in objects)
{
DataRow dr = dt.NewRow();
foreach (DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
{
dr[dc.ColumnName] = o.GetType().GetProperty(dc.ColumnName).GetValue(o, null);
}
dt.Rows.Add(dr);
}
return dt;
}
return null;
}
}
public class Rootobject
{
public Root[] root { get; set; }
}
public class Root
{
public string prog_id { get; set; }
public string prog_name { get; set; }
public string prog_banner { get; set; }
public string isClientActive { get; set; }
public Cours[] courses { get; set; }
}
public class Cours
{
public string course_id { get; set; }
public string course_name { get; set; }
public string course_description { get; set; }
public string course_thumbnail { get; set; }
}
```

```html
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "prog_id") %>">:<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"prog_name") %>
<ul>
<li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "courses") %></li>
</ul>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: please intent your code

Comment: you can't get values of nested array automatically by ``.GetValue(o, null)``, you should loop if the property is an array to build new list of course names. in this case ``DataColumn`` must be ``dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn(pi.Name, typeof(List<string>)));`` i can add an answer, but i don't know how to map list of string in the view for courses. it's simple if you want courses separated by ``;`` like a string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all you don't need `GetDataTableFromObjects` method since you have already data so that you can bind it to repeater directly.

```
Rootobject _objRoot = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Rootobject>(json);
Repeater1.DataSource = _objRoot.root;
Repeater1.DataBind();
```

And you can use nested repeater to display `courses` as follow. (I'm assuming that you want to show `course_name` of `courses`)

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "prog_id") %> : <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem,"prog_name") %>
         <br />Courses: <br />
        <ul>
            <asp:Repeater ID="CourseRepeater" runat="server" DataSource='<%# Eval("courses") %>'>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <li><%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "course_name") %></li>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:Repeater>
        </ul>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

See: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/306154/how-to-display-hierarchical-data-by-using-nested-repeater-controls-and

It will give you desired output:

```
P1000004 : Course1  
Courses:
 - Course1-1 
 - Course1-2

P1000010 : Course2  
Courses:
 - Course2-1 
 - Course2-2 
 - Course2-3 
 - Course2-4
 - Course2-5
```